# Segmentation Fault 11 while type-checking

Tags: swift, uitableview, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

today I upgraded my development mac to Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.5 and with that to the latest Xcode Version. Now without any changes my project won't compile anymore. 
I get `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11`.
At the bottom of the stack-trace it says 
`1. While type-checking 'tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)' at /.../BodyweightTableViewController.swift:227:14
2.  While type-checking expression at [/.../BodyweightTableViewController.swift:234:15 - line:234:123] RangeText="self.bodyweights[startIndex..<self.bodyweights.count].indices.contains(endIndex) && (endIndex-startIndex) < 7"`

The named method looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    ...

    var titleHeader = ... # some initialisation

    ... # some calculations that may alter the header

    return titleHeader
}
```

I am totally clueless what's the problem here. I looked at some other questions here but they didn't seem to help me.

/Edit: I changed this line

```
 while self.bodyweights[startIndex..<self.bodyweights.count].indices.contains(endIndex) && (endIndex-startIndex) < 7  {
        endIndex += 1
    }
```

to this one

```
while (self.bodyweights[startIndex..<self.bodyweights.count] as! ArraySlice<Bodyweight>).indices.contains(endIndex) && (endIndex-startIndex) < 7 {
        endIndex += 1
    }
```

and now I don't get the error anymore even though it says that the forced cast to same type has no effect.
Can somebody explain this to me?